# My NGINX suddenly becomes inactive in Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I deployed a Laravel (PHP) application on DigitalOcean Ubuntu-18 using NGINX. Everything was working perfectly, until suddenly the server application stopped.

I observed that NGINX is inactive and I tried to restart, but failed.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: run nginx -t , put the logs here

Comment: When I ran nginx -t, I got this:                                nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved Thanks.

This is what I did:

```
ps -ef |grep nginx

netstat -tulpn |grep 80

service nginx start
```

Thanks